# Yii - CJuiDialog Close on submit button click

Tags: dialog, onclick, yii

I have a CJuiDialog  and below is the code

```
<?php $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
    'id'=>'mymodal',
    'options'=>array(
        'title'=>'Your 10 seconds take you into ....',
        'width'=>700,
        'height'=>400,
        'autoOpen'=>true,
        'resizable'=>false,
        'modal'=>true,
        'closeOnEscape' => false,     
    ),

)); ?>
```

In this dialog I have form and in the form I have below submit button

```
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit', array('onclick'=>'js:function(){ alert("test"); $(#mymodal).dialog("close");}',
        )); ?>
```

on clicking on this button, I want to close this dialog and submit the form . But the above code what I wrote in Button is not working . any syntax errors ?

Other way I tried is , I used buttons in the dialog box and able to close the dialog using

```
`js:function(){$(this).dialog("close")`
```

But I am not able to submit the form there . So took the first approach .

Could any one help me the correct solution ?

Thanks and Regards

Kiran

Comment: i have a solution if you are still interested in one.

Comment: Thank You Bool Dev . Sorry I I just saw your comment . Could you please post the answer and It will be useful . Thanks again

Comment: hey, looking at your question again, can you tell me how is the "button not working" for you, i mean what error are you getting? See when you have a submit button, a new page is loaded, so you won't being seeing the dialog anyway, unless you are loading the same page again. So can you also share your code in the action that is handling the form submission? Sorry for the late reply, i was taking a holiday :)

Comment: I am sorry again , some how I am not getting the comments to my inbox and missing peoples comments, I will double check my account settings . I am sorry again , I will check for the code and post it here if I found it . Too many things happened and don't know where the code is now . Thank You

Comment: Thats ok just make sure in your next reply, that you answer all the questions i have asked in comment of Jan 20. Most importantly, tell me how is the button not working for you? what output were you expecting and what was actually happening?

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to get the submit-button working? I'm facing the same problem..

Comment: @Thijs i have posted a solution below, which should give you some pointers

Comment: i have submitted a solution below, have a look, and if needed do ask for clarifications.

Answer (score 6):

First of all you have to understand/remember that by default a html submit button *navigates to* or *loads* the action url of the form. So, provided your *action url* is correctly specified, the default button will simply submit the form and navigate to that url.

1. If this happens and the action url and the current page url are not the same, you'll not be seeing the dialog box again anyway(due to the navigation).
2. But incase your action url and current url are the same<sup>*</sup>, then obviously after default submission the same url will be loaded again, and since your dialog is `'autoOpen'=>true`, it will open again.

So the best course of action i can see for you is using [jquery's ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to submit your form. This can be done in 3 ways:

1. Use [`ajaxSubmitButton()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxSubmitButton-detail) directly in the form:

   ```
   echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('SubmitThis',
       $url, // form's action url, you can use createUrl 
       array( // ajaxOptions, use success to close the dialog
          'success'=>'function(){$("#mymodal").dialog("close");}'
       )
   );
   ```
2. Use a button of the dialog to submit the form. The sample below uses [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) shorthand to post an ajax request, and [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to serialize the form data:

   ```
   // other cjuidialog options
   // ...
   'buttons'=>array(
       'Submit'=>'js:function(){
                   $.post(
                       $("#form-id").attr("action"), // the url to submit to
                       $("#form-id").serialize(), // the data is serialized
                       function(){$("#mymodal").dialog("close");} // in the success the dialog is closed
                   );
              }',
       // other buttons
   )
   ```
3. You can also use the normal submit button but you'll have to use ajax again:

   ```
   'onclick'=>'$.post(
                 $("#form-id").attr("action"), // the url to submit to
                 $("#form-id").serialize(), // the data is serialized
                 function(){$("#mymodal").dialog("close");}
               );
              return false; // to prevent the navigation to the action url
              '
   ```

---

[*] if you are using [CActiveForm](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#action-detail) and haven't specified the `'action'` this happens by default

Comment: Seeing that this question is still generating traffic, i have added this answer. i think it solves the problems thoroughly(if i understood your question correctly), anyway do have a look. @Thijs check this answer, i think you could get some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't put `js:` in your `onclick` value. The right prefix is `javascript:` and it is unneeded in `on*` whose values are always scripts, by default in Javascript.

Secondly, you defined an anonymous JS function that is never called.

Then learn to use a JS console to see the errors, and a JS debugger to run your code step by step. In Firefox, you can use the firebug extension. In Chrome or Opera, press `Ctrl-Shift-I` to open the developer block that contains the JS tools. Then it will be easy to fix your JS code that is currently:

```
function(){
    alert("test");
    $(#mymodal).dialog("close");
}
```

See the errors? There should be no function as noted above, and you forgot to quote a text.

Comment: sorry thought I responded . Even this one not helping :( . Something to do with Yii framework format