# Yii Ajax Submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

Yii 1.1.14

I'm trying to make a popup to select a year and then get some reporting output for the selected year :

[image]

The popup is generated by CJuiDialog.
Inside CJuiDialog', I have a form.
In the first time I had a normal submit button on the form and it worked fine.
But it did not close the popup.
Then I found this post : [Yii - CJuiDialog Close on submit button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149391/yii-cjuidialog-close-on-submit-button-click)
The button of the dialog to submit the form closes the dialog but seems not to post to the indicated url. 
I also tried ajaxSubmitButton() directly in the form. 
Same result when I click on this button.
There are no JS errors, nothing in the application log.

This is my View :

```
<div class="reporting">
    <?php 
        $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
            'id'=>'mydialog',
            'options'=>array(
                'title'=>'select year test',
                'autoOpen'=>false,
                'modal'=>true,
                'buttons' => array(
                    'Dialog Submit Button'=>'js:function(){
                        $.post(
                            $("#select-year-form").attr("action"),
                            $("#select-year-form").serialize(),
                            function(){$("#mydialog").dialog("close");}                     
                        );
                    }',             
                        array('text'=>Yii::t('app','reporting.select.close'),'click'=> 'js:function(){$(this).dialog("close");}'),
                ),
            ),
        ));
    ?>
    <div class="well">
        <?php echo     CHtml::beginForm(CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('/site/about')),'post',array('id'=>'select-year-form')); ?>
        <table class="contentheader">
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo CHtml::DropDownList('year', $lastyear, $yearslist, array('options'=>array($lastyear=>array('selected'=>true)) )); ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        <?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Form Ajax Submit Button',
                CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('/site/about')), 
                array('success'=>'function(){$("#mydialog").dialog("close");}'),
                array('name' => 'run', 'class' => 'btn btn-success')
        ); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
    </div>

    <?php 
        $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
        echo CHtml::link(Yii::t('app','app.menu.reporting.planning.xlsabsence'), '#', array(
            'onclick'=>'$("#mydialog").dialog("open"); return false;',
        ));
    ?>
</div>
```

**EDIT :**
Here's the requestheader for the ajax submit button :

```
Request URL:http://localhost/yii02/yiiars02/index.php?r=site/about
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,de;q=0.2
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:9
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:b594784e48e60bab8dd41b584687725e=04rsh9hf09a4ef2f4a0in4prg7; e34b39f8afcdd208672f91abc90c8ad5=eqp4uva5819mj068b2n2qf3nu2; jpanesliders_panel-sliders=0; jpanesliders_position-icon=0; gantry-admin-tab=3; f6ea8ae4b9346c959ddbac3f5fefea4b=kk6g5oahbmql62rqkdiafem904; 60c5ada15aad7e760a944539ad24030d=bhf70j5o138vlse6m1gsmv49k6; 098c7ced18d50e0c9e49b567bc9f0832=fr-FR; 160a24a8bbe9b9a4500e829a48ae3415=e72bkntgosf81tbg26s6nk39j6; 25c0d40cd6ace920e960f397705968e5=pdgqudpu2psp5dpag72tol5tp0; PHPSESSID=31sij28hcolr3r1ip39rugmf62
Host:localhost
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/yii02/yiiars02/index.php?r=planning/test
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
r:site/about
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
year:2014
```

**Response Headersview source**

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:4810
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Mon, 10 Feb 2014 09:56:39 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) PHP/5.4.21
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.21
```

For the other button its the same request header.
There appears no error - so why can't I see the page r=site/about ?
(actually r=site/about is just a test page, I will have to do the target page when I have resolved this problem).

Comment: i think it is submitting form but in actionIndex(). Please check whether it is submitting to actionIndex by putting code CVarDumper::Dump($_GET,100,true),die() in actionIndex. If it is submitting in index then above code will be called.

Comment: Hello - thanks - I put the code in actionIndex but nothing changed.
When clicking one of the 2 submit buttons the only thing that visibly happens is that the dialog is closed.

Comment: Ok, that means if your success function is being called then ajax request has been made. Have you checked the request header under inspect element->Network?

Comment: Ok got your question. actually the above response as you can see is returning "Content-Type:text/html". If you want to render the whole page again then why are you using ajaxbutton? ajax is always used for partial update in page. You have to mention the element which you want to update. So tell me which element of page do u want to update? is it gridview that u wan to update or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls are made for partial update on page not the whole page. First you have to define id for the element you want to update. for example

```
<div id='myDiv'>
</div>
```

Now in you `ajaxSubmitButton` code write

```
 <?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Form Ajax Submit Button',
                CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('/site/about')), 
                array('success'=>'function(){$("#mydialog").dialog("close");}',
                      'update'=>'#myDiv'                            ),
                array('name' => 'run', 'class' => 'btn btn-success')
        ); ?>
```

When the response is received the the id to be update is updated accordingly. Remember you can update any element by setting id for that.

Comment: You're certainly right about ajax. I was not looking to use ajax. But I found this post (see my initial post) and thought this might solve my issues. In an ideal world I would like to get this process : open the popup, select a year, submit calls the action to generate a pdf file. This pdf generation is quite long so it would be nice to have some kind of "loading" gif image. When the pdf file is generated close popup and show a flash message to tell the user that the pdf has been gerated successfully. So if someone can give me some hints to how come close to this scenario would be nice

Answer (score 0):

I got work the process but the result is a downloaded file that can not be read by Excel :

I introduced this ajax submit button :

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Form Ajax Submit Button',
    CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('/planning/xlsAbsences')), 
    array(
        'type'=>'POST',
        'beforeSend' => "function(request) { console.log('beforeSend'); }",
        'data'=>'js:$("#select-year-form").serialize()+"&year="+$("#dropDownId :selected").text()',
        'success'=>'function(response, status, request){    
            $("#mydialog").dialog("close"); 
            var disp = request.getResponseHeader("Content-Disposition");
            if (disp && disp.search("attachment") != -1) {
                var filename = disp.substring(21).replace("\"","");
                var form = $("<form method=\"POST\" action=\"index.php?r=planning/dl\">");
                form.append($("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"content\" value=\"" + request.responseText + "\">"));
                form.append($("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"filename\" value=\"" + filename + "\">"));
                $("body").append(form);
                form.submit();
            }
            console.log(filename);
            console.log(request.responseText);
        }',
        'complete' => "function(request) { console.log(request); }",
        'error' => "function(data) { alert('erro'+data); }",
    ),
    array('name' => 'run', 'class' => 'btn btn-success')
); ?>
```

I created a new action as target for the form action - its called actionDl :

```
public function actionDl()
{
    $filename = $_POST['filename'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    echo $content;
}
```

I thought that request.responseText contains the content of the excel file, but perhaps I'm wrong about that ?